# Collect a specific attribute from the last appearance of an element

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname, getattribute

```
function refresh_images() {
    if (!document.images) return;
    const totalimages = document.querySelectorAll("img").length;
    const lastimages = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[totalimages].getAttribute('name').replace("grafico-betfair-", "");
}
```

[image]

I'm trying to collect the element called `name="grafico-betfair-5"` but it returns an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute') at refresh_images
```

What should I change in my code so I can retrieve the value?

Comment: Why are you reading the length which is already greater than the number of images since it starts at index zero and you add one? Why are we  mixing querySelectorAll and getElementsByTagName?

Comment: Sorry @epascarello There are other parts of the code that I didn't want to share, I've edited it and put the result with the correct length, the error remains.

Comment: You want `document.getElementsByTagName('img')[totalimages-1]`. `.length` returns the last index+1, so you need to subtract one from length to get the last number

Comment: Unless you somehow add two images between those two lines, it is not going to work. My guess is you meant to do `- 1` instead of `+ 1`

Comment: Now after you fix that, unsure why you are selecting the attribute and using a value. There is no value of a string.

Comment: Hi @epascarello Actually, I had to put ```-1``` to recover the value of the fourth image, I was able to understand what you said, because it starts counting from ```0``` and not from ```1```. Thank you very much! Please if you can, create the answer so I can mark it as a solved question, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last image by using the last *index* which you can get by deducting 1 from the *length* of the *NodeList*.

And also, as [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) ***method does not change the calling String object. It returns a new string***, you need to set the attribute with the new name.

**Demo:**

```js
//get all the images
const totalImages =  document.querySelectorAll('img');
//get the last image
const lastImage = totalImages[totalImages.length - 1];
//get the new image name
const lastImageName = lastImage.getAttribute('name').replace("grafico-betfair-", "");
//set the new name
lastImage.setAttribute('name', lastImageName);
//print the last image
console.log(lastImage);
```

```html
<img name="test1" src="/img1.jpg"/>

<img name="grafico-betfair-test" src="/img2.jpg"/>
```